# Move through keys in a dictionary in an order python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary like this:

```
{(4, 4, 'TO'): '1.0', (5, 3, 'NNP'): '0.061274509803921566', (3, 3, 'VBP'): '0.07894736842105263', (3, 3, 'VB'): '0.012048192771084338', (2, 2, 'X_TO'): '1.0', (0, 0, 'NP_PRP'): '0.3235294117647059', (6, 6, 'NNP'): '0.051470588235294115', (1, 2, 'VBP'): '0.02631578947368421', (2, 3, 'TO'): '1.0', (4, 4, 'X_TO'): '1.0'}
```

Where keys are tuples of (int, int, str).

I want to loop over it (in a `for` loop) in the order of the leftmost tuple integer least to greatest. So, it would first loop: `(0, 0, 'NP_PRP')` then `(1, 2, 'VBP')`. 
Order after the first integer doesn't matter.

Comment: Please edit the question with your current code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then do that. Tuples automatically sort by first element order. (then second element order, etc).

```
d = {(4, 4, 'TO'): '1.0', (5, 3, 'NNP'): '0.061274509803921566', (3, 3, 'VBP'): '0.07894736842105263', (3, 3, 'VB'): '0.012048192771084338', (2, 2, 'X_TO'): '1.0', (0, 0, 'NP_PRP'): '0.3235294117647059', (6, 6, 'NNP'): '0.051470588235294115', (1, 2, 'VBP'): '0.02631578947368421', (2, 3, 'TO'): '1.0', (4, 4, 'X_TO'): '1.0'}

for T in sorted(d):
  print(T)

#(0, 0, 'NP_PRP')
#(1, 2, 'VBP')
#(2, 2, 'X_TO')
#(2, 3, 'TO')
#..
```

Comment: `sorted(d)` would suffice